# Difference between grunt-useref and grunt-usemin?

Tags: gruntjs

On the GitHub page for grunt-useref it says: "Inspiration (and large chunks of code) for grunt-useref was taken from the usemin tasks of H5BP and Yeoman."

What are the actual differences between the two projects?

Answer (score 2):

They seem to do be able to do pretty much the same job, namely concat, minify, and replace original html references to use the generated files. grunt-usemin is nowadays used as a pre- and post-hook around concatenation&minification in grunt, while grunt-useref

From looking at the docs as well as the repository statistics one can spot actual differences as follows:

### [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin)

#### Project Facts:

- Project Start: unclear, sometime before Dec 2012 (1st github commit, tagged with version 0.1.11)
- Contributors: **>=40**
- current version: v2.1.0 (released **March 2014**)
- has a continuous integration process via travis and seems reasonably covered by unit tests

#### Tasks

- `useminPrepare` parses the html blocks with for files to process and produces a configuration block for concatenation & minification tasks for inclusion in your gruntfile
- `usemin` does the job of replacing those original blocks with links to the target files, thus modifying those files

### [grunt-useref](https://github.com/pajtai/grunt-useref)

#### Project Facts:

- Project Start: Oct 2012
- Contributors: **1**
- current version: v0.0.16 (released **March 2013**)

As noted above, grunt-useref is partially forked off grunt-usemin in Oct 2012, [reusing the usemin task code at that time under the name of `useref`](https://github.com/pajtai/grunt-useref/commit/f8ca24d762d855d25fbf9c4d132d9bb73b51d772#diff-4be0e0790795923d836526acbcc87d2cL75), which appears to only have been [patched](https://github.com/pajtai/grunt-useref/blame/master/tasks/useref.js#L184) for recent grunt version compatbility.

#### Tasks:

- `useref` parses the blocks, concatenates, minifies, and replaces the blocks in the original .html files  in one go